# How to load data from csv with torchtext 0.12.0

Tags: python, torch, torchtext

I am trying to figure out the new method to load a csv dataset for Torchtext, but I can't find any clear explanations.

Given a csv with two columns: `text, class`, all of the tutorials I can find for torchtext load data like this:

```
tokenizer = lambda x: re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z ]", "", x).split()

text = Field(sequential = True, use_vocab = True, tokenize = tokenizer, lower = True)
class = Field(sequential = False, use_vocab = False)
fields = {'text': ('text', text), 'class':('class', class)}

train_data, test_data = TabularDataset.splits(
    path = 'data_directory/',
    train = 'train.csv',
    test = 'test.csv',
    format = 'csv',
    fields = fields
)

text.build_vocab(train_data, max_size=10000, min_freq=10)

train_iterator, test_iterator = BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, test_data), batch_size = 2, device = "cpu"
)
```

Above modified from [this git repository](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/blob/master/ML/Pytorch/more_advanced/torchtext/torchtext_tutorial1.py)

But I can't find any tutorial on loading data with newer versions of torchtext. New torchtext does not even include the legacy code. How can one load a csv with the new torchtext 0.12.0?

Answer (score 1):

```
from torchdata.datapipes.iter import FileOpener, IterableWrapper
def get_data(split = "train"):
    url_dp = IterableWrapper([f"{split}.csv"])
    data_dp = FileOpener(url_dp, mode="b")
    return data_dp.parse_csv().map(fn=lambda t: (t[0], t[1] ))
```

I used IterableWrapper and FileOpener to parse my csvs. You can then pass this to a DataLoader to get the required dataloaders. I think torchtext removed the csv loading component to reduce redundancy since torchdata takes care of all the data processing use-cases.

Hope this helps.

Edit 2 : https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/711#issuecomment-1154000107 : Got the same response from the torch team.